# jquery/Javascript syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am trying to figure out what the below syntax do. It's code from Bootstraps popover.

```
//title is a string
$tip.find('.popover-title')[ $.type(title) == 'object' ? 'append' : 'html' ](title)
                           ^                                                 ^
                       What does this symbol mean?                    Whats happening here?
```

Comment: @pimvdb It did that in older versions of jQuery as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's break it up:

```
$tip.find('.popover-title')[ $.type(title) == 'object' ? 'append' : 'html' ](title)
```

It can be broken down into this:

```
var found = $tip.find('.popover-title');
found[$.type(title) == 'object' ? 'append' : 'html'](title);
```

And more:

```
var found = $tip.find('.popover-title');

if ($.type(title) == 'object') {
  found['append'](title);
} else {
  found['html'](title);
}
```

A little more:

```
var found = $tip.find('.popover-title');

if ($.type(title) == 'object') {
  found.append(title);
} else {
  found.html(title);
}
```

Comment: Ahhhh Blendy. You just had to upstage me :-P

Comment: This is not 100% correct. You lose the implicit `this` value to `found` in the `func` assignments.

Comment: @pimvdb: What do you mean? I don't really see `this` used in the code.

Comment: @Blender: In your code `func === $.fn.append` or `func === $.fn.html`; to use it *on the element* (set the `this` value correctly) you'd have to do `func.call(found, title)`. Only if you do `foo.append()`, the `this` value is set automatically to `foo`.

Answer (score 5):

It is basically saying:

```
if(typeof title == 'object') {
    $tip.find('.popover-title').append(title);
}
else {
    $tip.find('.popover-title').html(title);
}
```

The `[...]` notation allows for you dynamically select the function from the `$tip.find('.popover-title')` object.

Comment: Here, have some compensation ;) Does `$.type()` actually do anything other than wrap `typeof` in a function? I don't really see why you would need to use `$.type()` in this code at all...

Comment: @Blender hehe hence I used `typeof`. jQuery likes making up functions for things that exist already :-P

Comment: @Blender although it seems it may have more features to detect more things. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.type/

Answer (score 2):

`$("selector")["append"](...)` is equal to `$("selector").append(...)`